# Question about matrix representation according to different basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $T:V➜V$ be a linear
> transformation.
>
> Assume there exists two ordered basis $B,C$ such that
> $\left[T\right]_{B}^{C}=\left[T\right]_{C}^{B}=I_{V}$. Prove or disprove:
> $T=I_{V}$

The answer is false, as taking B=((1,0),(0,1)), C=((1,0),(0,-1)) will contradict the statement.

But I don't understand what is wrong with my proof:

Taking $B=(v_{1},...,v_{n}), C=(u_{1},...,u_{n})$

$\left[T\right]_{B}^{C}=\left(\left[T\left(v_{1}\right)\right]_{C}\ \ ...\ \left[T\left(v_{n}\right)\right]_{C}\right)=I_{V}=\left(\left[T\left(u_{1}\right)\right]_{B}\ \ ...\ \ \left[T\left(u_{n}\right)\right]_{B}\right)=\left[T\right]_{C}^{B}$

Which means

$T\left(v_{1}\right)=1\cdot u_{1}+0\cdot u_{2}+...+0\cdot u_{n}$

$T\left(v_{2}\right)=0\cdot u_{1}+1\cdot u_{2}+...+0\cdot u_{n}$

.

.

$T\left(v_{n}\right)=0\cdot u_{1}+0\cdot u_{2}+...+1\cdot u_{n}$

Therefore we can conclude that $T\left(v_{i}\right)=u_{i}$ for every $1\le i\le n$, and in the same way we can show $T\left(u_{i}\right)=v_{i}$ for every $1\le i\le n$, which means the following must hold:

$T\left(v_{i}\right)+T\left(u_{i}\right)=u_{i}+v_{i}\ \ \ ➜\ \ \ T\left(v_{i}+u_{i}\right)=v_{i}+u\ \ \ ➜\ \ \ T=I_{V}$

Which step did I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The step that is wrong is

$$T(u_i + v_i) = u_i + v_i \text{ for all } i\implies T=I_V$$ as $\{u_i+v_i\}$ may not be a basis. This is by the way the case for your initial example as $u_2 + v_2 = 0$.

An even simpler case in the one-dimensional vector space $\mathbb R$ with $B=(1), C=(-1)$ and $T(x) = -x$. You have

$$\left[T\right]_{B}^{C}=\left[T\right]_{C}^{B}$$ but $T = -I_V \neq I_V$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! :) Can you explain further why it has to be a basis in order for the conclusion to be true?

Comment: Suppose for example that all $u_i+v_i=0$. Then the equations $T(u_i+v_i)=u_i+v_i$ are just $T(0)=0$. Which is true for any linear map.